# Apache FCGI PHP-FPM Mac OS X 10.8 unable to bind

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, fastcgi, php-fpm

So I have found a [few](https://serverfault.com/questions/308820/ubuntu-php-fpm-not-starting) [other](https://serverfault.com/questions/426934/php-fpm-bind-issues) threads about this kind of issue, but their solutions aren't working for me.

Basically, this is my development machine and the setup has been fine for a number of weeks now, but suddenly I'm getting a lot of issues with these errors:

```
[Thu Sep 27 16:28:43 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: comm with server "/Library/WebServer/Documents/php5.external" aborted: idle timeout (60 sec)
[Thu Sep 27 16:28:43 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Library/WebServer/Documents/php5.external"
```

I haven't changed anything related to the server config. Obviously something must've changed, or I've just become unlucky..

Setup is as follows:

```
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8r

$ php-fpm -v
PHP 5.3.15 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Aug 19 2012 09:06:12)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

$ sudo lsof -i TCP:9000
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
php-fpm 97167 _www    6u  IPv4 0xd65451f140772337      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm 97174 _www    0u  IPv4 0xd65451f140772337      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener (LISTEN)
php-fpm 97174 _www    3u  IPv4 0xd65451f14739c337      0t0  TCP localhost:cslistener->localhost:54750 (CLOSE_WAIT)

$ tail -16 /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    FastCGIExternalServer /Library/WebServer/Documents/php5.external -flush -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -idle-timeout 60
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5.external
    Alias /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ /Library/WebServer/Documents/

    <Directory /usr/local/sbin>
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
        SetHandler fastcgi-script
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

It's pretty much a default php-fpm.conf with the log location changed, ondemand process manager, pm.max_children = 1 and everything else is default.

I've tried restarting apache dozens of times, and killing all the php-fpm processes, in different orders.

Any suggestions will be wildly encouraged, welcomed, appreciated, tried and hoped for.

**UPDATE 28/09/2012**

Okay, so I used [this](http://www.group7even.com/blog/2012/02/23/installing-nginx-php-fpm-on-os-x-mountain-lion-10-8/) tutorial and tried the socket approach to see if it was a TCP port collision - turns out its not. Using sockets also didn't help the every-10-second error messages like these:

For TCP:

```
[28-Sep-2012 08:44:58] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (48)
[28-Sep-2012 08:44:58] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (48)
[28-Sep-2012 08:44:58] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[28-Sep-2012 08:44:58] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

For sockets:

```
[28-Sep-2012 08:48:32] ERROR: An another FPM instance seems to already listen on /tmp/php5-fpm.sock
[28-Sep-2012 08:48:32] ERROR: An another FPM instance seems to already listen on /tmp/php5-fpm.sock
[28-Sep-2012 08:48:32] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[28-Sep-2012 08:48:32] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

I did figure out how to solve this though, and it's in the tutorial I just linked. The launch agent plist configuration needs to specify RunOnlyOnce. Not sure if this is safe for TCP though.

I do have some progress though, which might make this question too specific.. I use NetBeans for development, and when I tried to fire up a debug session using xdebug, it loads fine - cool - but as soon as the code needs pause on a breakpoint, I'm back at square 1. `comm with server ... aborted: idle timeout`

Just to cover all my bases, I set -idle-timeout in httpd.conf to 300. No dice.
If I shutdown Netbeans and don't try (ever) starting a debug session, the server won't die, it'll behave as intended.

I'm about to try rebooting my MacBook, but honestly that shouldn't be a valid solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured I better comment back on this seeing as nobody else has.

I have NO idea how to stop PHP-FPM from logging the binding errors over and over again when listening via TCP.

I solved my problem by switching to unix socket listening, and configuring the launch agent to run PHP-FPM only once on startup.

Best I could do. Maybe this will help someone, idk.

In `php-fpm.conf`

```
listen = /tmp/php5-fpm.sock
```

In `httpd.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
    Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
    Alias /php5-fcgi /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/php-fcgi
    FastCGIExternalServer /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/php-fcgi -socket /tmp/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 300

    <Directory /usr/local/sbin>
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
        SetHandler fastcgi-script
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

In `/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew-php.josegonzalez.php53.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew-php.josegonzalez.php53</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.15/sbin/php-fpm</string>
      <string>--fpm-config</string>
      <string>/usr/local/etc/php/5.3/php-fpm.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Username</key>
    <string>www</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/var</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.15/var/log/php-fpm.log</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do l s-lA in you project and find out which user you are and group . and edit the `php-fpm.conf` for php-fpm5.6 and `www.conf` for php7.* version

In my case my user = vallabh and group = staff

and update the listen = 127.0.0.1:9071 and listen = 127.0.0.1:9056

it's quite handy and easy to remember the port.

happy coding.

use bellow shell code to verify that you are binding the port.

`lsof -Pni4 | grep LISTEN | grep php`